# Is 'couple' ever used in the sense of 'some'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, grammatical-number

Is the usage of the word *couple* (as in, *"I want to ask a couple of questions..."*) to mean 'some' or 'few' correct (as in, interpreting given example to mean *"I want to ask a few questions"*)?

As a follow-up on the example, when someone says *"I want to ask a couple of questions..."*, does the usage of 'couple' necessarily mean the two questions have to be related to each other, or can couple just mean 'two' in that context?

Comment: I'm asking because I came across someone who use 'couple' in the sense of 'handful' today and...it just seems like incorrect usage to me.

Comment: Related: [Why is 'a couple of <things>' often shortened to 'a couple <things>'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/why-is-a-couple-of-things-often-shortened-to-a-couple-things)

Comment: That's American usage, I believe.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/couple-vs-few

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. It's used all the time to mean an undefined small quantity.

> Come here, I want to ask you a couple of questions.

This is likely to be more than two questions.

> I've had a couple of ideas I'd like to go over with you.

Translation: Get ready to be bored.

But if you use it regarding specific items, it probably means just two:

> Can you bring me back a couple of Cokes from the machine?

But don't be surprised if the person replies:

> Sure. How many do you want?

Comment: I would say that in England I expect "couple" to mean a collection of indeterminate size, except in relation to persons referred to as "a couple". By contrast "a couple of them" would be an indeterminate, but probably small group of persons.

Comment: I would generally expect it to mean 2, maybe 3--honestly if it were more than two you should use few, however it can be a lower bound--I can think of two questions but I may have follow-ons, that would be a good usage.

Comment: And if you're in the in the south of USA, don't be surprised if the person replies "Sure. What brand?" (or so I've heard).

Comment: Exactly parallel, I think. Here in Tennessee, if someone asked me for "a couple of Cokes" I would fetch two Coca Colas without asking for clarification. But in other contexts, the meaning of *Coke*, like *couple*, can be less specific.

Comment: As far as I know, even in rural Georgia *Coke* is only generic in contexts where there is little danger of confusion, like *I need to get to the store and get some Cokes.* But there are plenty of places I haven’t been.

Answer (score 4):

*Couple* originally referred to a pairing (as in two things that go together) and later developed into simply meaning *two* but has since widened its meaning to *a few* or *a handful*.

Comment: What was interesting to me was when a friend recently insisted that she uses *a few* to mean *two* and *a couple* to mean *three or more*.

Comment: No, few is more than couple, couple would be 2 and maybe more (uncertain), but if it's 3 or more it would be few.  5 or more would be handfull.

Comment: @Bill K I was not suggesting my friend is right (see my answer above) but rather pointing out something I found humorous.

Comment: I find that in my country of residence (NZ), a couple 99% of the time means just two, no more. Very iritating.

Comment: And when we hear about 'the happy couple', there's really not much doubt it means only two. I would describe the use of *couple* to mean more than two as *maddeningly imprecise*.

Comment: Great summary. Incidentally, The New Oxford American Dictionary defines the widened sense as 'an indefinite small number' and classifies this usage as informal.