# “every couple months” vs. “every couple of months"

Tags: word-usage

Consider this sentence:

> For most patients, he will monitor you once every **couple (of)** months

Which is correct: "couple" or "couple of"?

Comment: What makes you think that one of those is wrong?

Comment: Not wrong specifically. I just thought one sounded better than the other.

Comment: I suspect that this addresses your question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2407

Comment: Thanks, but that discussion seemed to be mostly about the use of "couple" rather than "couple of".

Comment: Isn't that what you're asking though? I don't understand your question if that isn't it.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that both are correct. In the Corpus of Historical American English chart shown, it indicates that "couple of" is more commonly used.
I just need to know if one is incorrect. If they both are correct, that is all I need to know.
I am new to this site so perhaps I worded my question poorly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @tchrist♦: Maybe Cori's answer to that question answers this one to some extent, as the subject matter is similar; but it's somewhat hard to find for visitors, also because the title of that question is different. Only in this question do we have a clear question and a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

In formal English, I would say that the preposition is required.

Online definitions of *couple* in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couple), [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/couple), and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/couple) all give examples of its "pair" sense only with the preposition.

The *Associated Press Stylebook* says:

> The *of* is necessary. Never use *a couple tomatoes* or a similar phrase. The phrase takes a plural verb in constructions such as: *A couple of tomatoes were stolen.*

Here is more detailed analysis from the Government of Canada's [*TERMIUM Plus*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9kea-1LQpJao.html):

> Writers are often confused about when to include the preposition of after the phrase *a couple*. The guidelines below explain when the preposition should be included or omitted.
>
> ***A couple of*** **+ noun**
>
> When *a couple of* is used before a noun, writers often drop the preposition *of*, mistakenly using the noun *couple* as an adjective. This usage is informal and should be avoided in writing. The noun phrase *a couple* needs the preposition *of* to link it to another noun.
>
> Giovanni is having a couple *of* [*not* a couple] friends over for dinner.
>
> ***A couple of*** **+ adjective + noun**
>
> When *a couple of* is used before an adjective modifying a noun, the preposition *of* is needed to link the noun phrase *a couple* to the noun following the adjective.
>
> Brenda bought a couple **of** [*not* a couple] green papayas at the supermarket.
>
> ***A couple of*** **+ a number**
>
> When *a couple of* is used before a number such as dozen, hundred or thousand, the preposition *of* is needed to link the noun phrase *a couple* to the number.
>
> Ian gathered a couple **of** [*not* a couple] dozen eggs from the henhouse this morning.
>
> ***A couple*** **+ word of comparison or degree**
>
> When *a couple* is used immediately before a word or phrase of comparison or degree (e.g. *more*, *fewer*, *too few*, *too many*), the preposition *of* is dropped.
>
> Matilda ate a couple **more** [*not* a couple of more] slices of pizza than Serge did.
>
> However, if the word of comparison or degree appears later in the sentence, *a couple* is followed by *of*.
>
> Matilda ate a couple **of** slices **more** than Serge did.

Although people do drop the preposition, it seems to only be something regional or idiomatic.

So, both versions may be acceptable informally, but use the proposition for anything formal.

Comment: The OED says sense 7b for *couple* meaning  *couple of* is *“U.S. colloq.”* since 1876 through the present. Citation 2000   R. Barger et al. *Hell's Angel* xiv. 242   They suggested I just go home for a couple days. Cool out and have a good time.

Comment: +1 I am very pleased to read this answer.  I always use the "of" and for some reason I had always assumed I was in the wrong.

Comment: @Lumberjack I updated my answer with an even more detailed  analysis. ;)

Comment: This is a great answer Jason.  I wish I could upvote more.

Comment: @CarolHoffnagle If you feel this is the right answer, please consider marking this answer as correct with the check mark just beneath the question score.

Comment: @Knotell If I thought it was off topic, I would ignore it or vote to close it. I don't consider this off topic and I believe that the question and any answers are relevant to other people on this site. Not everybody thinks exactly the same way. :)

Comment: I am genuinely, politely asking you to answer my meta-question.